# Can I make my ANTLR4 Lexer discard a character from the input stream?

Tags: antlr4

I'm working on parsing PDF streams. In section 7.3.4.2 on literal string objects, the [PDF Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) says that a backslash within a literal string that isn't followed by an end-of-line character, one to three octal digits, or one of the characters "nrtbf()\" should be ignored. Is there a way to get the `recover` method in my lexer to ignore a backslash in this situation?

Here is my simplified parser:

```
parser grammar PdfStreamParser;

options { tokenVocab=PdfSteamLexer; } 

array: LBRACKET object* RBRACKET ;
dictionary: LDOUBLEANGLE (NAME object)* RDOUBLEANGLE ;
string: (LITERAL_STRING | HEX_STRING) ;
object
    : NULL
    | array
    | dictionary
    | BOOLEAN
    | NUMBER
    | string
    | NAME
    ;

content : stat* ;

stat
    : tj
    ;

tj: ((string Tj) | (array TJ)) ; // Show text
```

Here's the lexer. (Based on the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013009/76810) I'm not using a separate string mode):

```
lexer grammar PdfStreamLexer;

Tj: 'Tj' ;
TJ: 'TJ' ;

NULL: 'null' ;

BOOLEAN: ('true'|'false') ;

LBRACKET: '[' ;
RBRACKET: ']' ;
LDOUBLEANGLE: '<<' ;
RDOUBLEANGLE: '>>' ;

NUMBER: ('+' | '-')? (INT | FLOAT) ;

NAME: '/' ID ;

// A sequence of literal characters enclosed in parentheses.
LITERAL_STRING: '(' ( ~[()\\]+ | ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | LITERAL_STRING )* ')' ; 

// Escape sequences that can occur within a LITERAL_STRING
fragment ESCAPE_SEQUENCE 
    : '\\' ( [\r\nnrtbf()\\] | [0-7] [0-7]? [0-7]? )
    ;

HEX_STRING: '<' [0-9A-Za-z]+ '>' ; // Hexadecimal data enclosed in angle brackets

fragment INT: DIGIT+ ; // match 1 or more digits

fragment FLOAT:  DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*  // match 1. 39. 3.14159 etc...
    |         '.' DIGIT+  // match .1 .14159
    ;

fragment DIGIT:   [0-9] ;        // match single digit

// Accept all characters except whitespace and defined delimiters ()<>[]{}/%
ID: ~[ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000()<>[\]{}/%]+ ;

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000]+ -> skip ; // PDF defines six whitespace characters
```

I can override the recover method in the PdfStreamLexer class and get notified when the `LexerNoViableAltException` occurs, but I'm not sure how to (or if it's possible to) ignore the backslash and continue on with the LITERAL_STRING tokenization.

Comment: Perhaps you could treat ESCAPE_SEQUENCE as '\\' followed by an octal sequence or any character except '0' (handled by octal) or end-of-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to skip part of the string, you'll need to use lexical modes. Here's a quick demo:

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

STRING_OPEN
 : '(' -> pushMode(STRING_MODE)
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;

mode STRING_MODE;

  STRING_CLOSE
   : ')' -> popMode
   ;

  ESCAPE
   : '\\' ( [nrtbf()\\] | [0-7] [0-7] [0-7] )
   ;

  STRING_PART
   : ~[\\()]
   ;

  NESTED_STRING_OPEN
   : '(' -> type(STRING_OPEN), pushMode(STRING_MODE)
   ;

  IGNORED_ESCAPE
   : '\\' . -> skip
   ;
```

which can be used in the parser as follows:

```
parser grammar DemoParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=DemoLexer;
}

parse
 : ( string | OTHER )* EOF
 ;

string
 : STRING_OPEN ( ESCAPE | STRING_PART | string )* STRING_CLOSE
 ;
```

If you now parse the string `FU(abc(def)\@\))BAR`, you will get the following parse tree:

[image]

As you can see, the `\)` is left in the tree, but `\@` is omitted.

Comment: Thanks once again. Thinking like a parser is a lot different than thinking like a compiler. I still have a long way to go. The only change I needed to make was to remove the dot from IGNORED_ESCAPE since only the backslash is ignored, not the character after it. But the change works fine.

Comment: Ah, I see, only the backslash in `\@` is to be omitted and the `@` should stay. Then yes, you're right: `IGNORED_ESCAPE : '\\' -> skip;` is the way to go. And you're welcome, of course @SSteve